# Symfony2 Form - "You cannot change the data of a submitted form."

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have a form, where the user selects the preferred payment method. The name of the selected payment method is written in a hidden field "paymentMethod". After submission of the form, the system checks, if the payment is available for the customer (API of payment partners).

**Check ok:** User should be redirected to a confirmation page (No problem)

**Check failed:** User should see the form again, but the hidden field paymentMethod have to be set to null, so the selection box of the payements is visible again.

**Problem: You cannot change the data of a submitted form.**

Comment: This normally occurs when you try to modify the data in a form that has been loaded from the request (isSubmitted). Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when you call setData() on a form that is already 'submitted';

To set paymentMethod to null in this case, add a function to your `FormType` class:

```
/** 
 * this gets called in the final stage before rendering the form
 *
 * @return void
 */   
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    // set paymentMethod here
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to set the paymentMethod generally to null before rendering it. It should be only be null if the selected payment method is not available for the customer..

Answer (score -1):

The solution was really simple:

I added a function to my FormModel:

```
  public function resetPaymentMethod() {
    $this->paymentMethod = null;
  }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?